# Money change VBA

Tags: vb.net, uipath

I made a small code change money, but I have a small issue

the code is like this

```
Dim moneyHelper As Double
moneyHelper = 1.9

While moneyHelper > 0
  If moneyHelper > 25 Then
  Else If moneyHelper > 10 Then
  Else If moneyHelper > 5 Then
  Else If moneyHelper > 1 Then
    console.WriteLine("change $1 x " + Math.Floor(moneyHelper/1).ToString)
    moneyHelper = moneyHelper - (Math.Floor(moneyHelper/1)*1)
    console.WriteLine("result after $1: " + moneyHelper.ToString)
  Else If moneyHelper > 0.5 Then
    console.WriteLine("change $0.5 x " +  Math.Floor(moneyHelper/0.5).ToString)
    moneyHelper = moneyHelper - ( Math.Floor(moneyHelper/0.5)*0.5)
    console.WriteLine("result after $0.5: " + moneyHelper.ToString)
  Else If moneyHelper > 0.1 Then
    console.WriteLine("change $0.1 x " +  Math.Floor(moneyHelper/0.1).ToString)
    moneyHelper = moneyHelper - ( Math.Floor(moneyHelper/0.1)*0.1)
    console.WriteLine("result after $0.1: " + moneyHelper.ToString)
  End If
End While
```

But the result like this

```
change $1 x 1
result after $1: 0.9
change $0.5 x 1
result after $0.5: 0.4
change $0.1 x 3
result after $0.1: 0.0999999999999999
```

After the change, the result should be 0 and the change $0.1x4 but instead is 0.0999999999999999 and change $0.1x3. I don't know why.

I would appreciate any help from you guys! THANK YOU

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the `Double` type experiences rounding errors. Change to use `Decimal` and you should be fine. Google points to several links that cover this problem - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.net+double+rounding+errors

Comment: I tried to convert decimal but I have the same issue    `console.WriteLine("change $1 x " + (Math.Floor(moneyHelper/1.0)*1.0).ToString)`

Comment: 1.0 is a `Double`, you would want `1.0D` to ensure that the math is done using decimal throughout without conversions.

Comment: Toward @JayV comment, also try searching for "What every computer scientist should know about floating point".  I'd also recommend reading Bruce Dawson's blog series about floating point formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim moneyHelper As Decimal = 1.9D
    While moneyHelper > 0
        Select Case moneyHelper
            Case > 25D
               '?
            Case > 5D
               '?
            Case > 1D
                Console.WriteLine($"change $1 x {Math.Floor(moneyHelper / 1)}")
                moneyHelper -= CDec(Math.Floor(moneyHelper / 1) * 1)
                Console.WriteLine($"result after $1: {moneyHelper}")
            Case > 0.5D
                Console.WriteLine($"change $0.5 x {Math.Floor(moneyHelper / 0.5)}")
                moneyHelper -= CDec(Math.Floor(moneyHelper / 0.5) * 0.5)
                Console.WriteLine($"result after $0.5: {moneyHelper}")
            Case > 0.1D
                Console.WriteLine($"change $0.1 x {Math.Floor(moneyHelper / 0.1)}")
                moneyHelper -= CDec(Math.Floor(moneyHelper / 0.1) * 0.1)
                Console.WriteLine($"result after $0.1: {moneyHelper}")
            'Case Default?
               '?
        End Select
    End While
```

You could tighten this up by replacing the repeated code with a parametrized function but that not your question here. Also, as-is the code doesn't handle all values of `moneyHelper`, eg values <= 0.10 - refer `Case Default`.